# Problem: The turtle variable is of type int (-1, for example), but the patch variable is a one-element list ( [-1] ) in NetLogo 6.2

Tags: netlogo

I have one doubt:

Context: I have a code in which, briefly, turtles have an integer variable (energy-collected) and from that, patches update their own variable (energy-of-my-agent), as described in the code snippet below.

Problem: The turtle variable is of type int (-1, for example), but the patch variable is a one-element list ( [-1] ).

Question: Should this happen? Otherwise, how can I make the patch variable just an integer value?

```
ask turtles
[
  set energy-collected (energy - euse)
]

ask patches
[
    set energy-of-my-agent [energy-collected] of turtles-here
]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing you have to consider is what `of` [reports](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#of).

In your case `turtles-here` is an agentset, not a specific agent.

This is because, although you might have a single turtle on a patch, you may also have multiple turtles on a patch. Therefore `turtles-here` [reports an agentset](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#turtles-here), even if that agentset may be made of a single turtle.

It follows that a collection of values from an agentset, obtained with `of` (and `[energy-collected] of turtles-here` is exactly that), will be a list of values - even if that list contains only one element.

Therefore I would say:

- Is your model made in such a way that each patch **cannot** have more than one turtle at a time? Then you could do:

```
ask patches [
 if any? turtles-here [
  set energy-of-my-agent [energy-collected] of one-of turtles-here
  ]
]
```

In the code above, `one-of turtles-here` [reports a specific agent](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#one-of) - not an agentset anymore.
So its variable's value, obtained with `of`, will be stored as a single value (provided that the agent's variable is not a list itself, but that's not your case).

- Can it happen that your patches have more than one turtle at a time? Then, if you're interested in the single patch holding "its" turtles' values, dealing with lists is probably necessary.

### Update

I made a connection between this question and [your other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68850565/12391423) suggesting that you want to use patches as elements of matrices.

Maybe this is useful to your case: if your model allows for the possibility of having more than one turtle on the same patch, you might be interested in doing something like:

```
ask patches [
 set energy-of-my-agent sum [energy-collected] of turtles-here
]
```

As you can see, `sum` [takes a list as input and reports a number](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#sum). Each patch will take the sum of all the values of `energy-collected` by turtles standing there, or you can change the calculation using whatever you want (e.g. `mean`, `max` etc).

Actually, you can use this approach regardless: this way, even when you have a single turtle on a patch, `sum` (or any other function taking a lost and returning a value) will give you a single value where before you had a list of one value.