# How to adjust a file (to remove []) to export result in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I have a question and couldn't find an answer to it. The question is:

1. I have a code that exports the following result:

[image]

I would like the column (energy-of-my-agent) to be exported without the brackets [], like the figure below.

[image]

The code:

```
globals [ output-filename ]

turtles-own [ energy my-home ]

patches-own [ patch-id my-agent energy-of-my-agent ]

to setup
ca
reset-ticks
set output-filename "energy-of-my-agent.csv"
ask patches [
sprout 1
set patch-id [ who ] of turtles-here
set my-agent turtles-here ]
  ask turtles [
set my-home patch-here
set energy 0
]
  initialize-data-file
end
   

to initialize-data-file
  if output-data?
  [
    file-close-all

    if behaviorspace-run-number <= 1 [
      ;; we only want to delete the existing file if we're running in console
      ;; when running in console,  behaviorspace-run-number = 0,
      ;; first run in behavior space is behaviorspace-run-number = 1
      if file-exists? output-filename [
        file-delete output-filename
      ]
      ;; write a header to the file
      file-open output-filename
      file-print (word "run-number, ticks, energy-of-my-agent, pxcor, pycor" )
    ]
  ]
end

to go
ask turtles [
    let times repetitions
    repeat times [
let step random 5
fd step
set energy energy - step
  ]
  ]
ask patches [
    set energy-of-my-agent [ energy ] of my-agent
    if output-data? [
      if ticks mod output-every-n-ticks = 0  [       ;;output-every-n-ticks
        write-output-data energy-of-my-agent pxcor pycor
      ]
    ]
  ]

tick
end

to write-output-data [ #energy-of-my-agent #xpos #ypos ]

  file-open output-filename
  file-print (word  behaviorspace-run-number ", " ticks ", " #energy-of-my-agent ", " #xpos ", " #ypos  )
  file-flush
end
```

Is it possible? If so, how can I do this? Any kind of help is very welcome.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NetLogo, square brackets containing items represent a list.

In fact, the `energy-of-my-agent` variable in your output is in square brackets because it is a list (lists don't have to contain multiple items: empty lists or lists of one item are perfectly possible lists).

Why is `energy-of-my-agent` a list and not a single value? Because it comes from an agentset and not from an agent (as we already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68853417/12391423)).

The rule is:

- **reporter of agent -> single value** (unless the value is already a list in itself)
- **reporter of agentset -> list**

In your case: `energy-of-my-agent` is made by `[energy] of my-agent`, **and `my-agent` is an agentset, not an agent.**

Why so? Because `my-agent` is made by `turtles-here`, and **[`turtles-here` is an agentset](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#turtles-here), not an agent, even if it contains one only agent**. In the same way as lists, in fact, agentsets don't have to contain multiple agents: empty agentsets or agentsets of one agent are perfectly possible agentsets.

So you have three alternative options:

1. Use `set my-agent one-of turtles-here`. This will give you a single agent, because [`one-of` reports a single agent](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#one-of). If you are sure (as it seems to be the case) that patches will always only `sprout 1`, then `one-of turtles-here` will give you the exact same agent as `turtles-here` - but as an agent indeed, and not as an agentset. This in turn means that `[energy] of my-agent` will be a single value, and not a list of one value.
2. When outputting values, use `sum energy-of-my-agent`. In fact, [`sum` takes a list and reports a single value](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#sum). Given that the sum of a list of one value is exactly that value, in this case `sum` will report the only value in the list, but without square brackets.
3. When using `sprout 1`, you can make the new-born turtle assign itself to the patch: `sprout 1 [set my-agent self]`. This is possible because turtles can read and modify the variables of the patch they are on: in this case, the new turtle is able to operate on `my-agent` and, in particular, on `my-agent` of the patch it stands on.

I think that, between the three options above...

#2 is the least preferable: it never changes the fact that `my-agent` is an agentset (it only converts `energy-of-my-agent` from list to number at the end of the simulation), and I think this is not convenient in terms of memory and time because working with agentsets is a heavier process than working with agents.

#1 does not have this problem, because from the beginning it makes sure that `my-agent` is an agent and not an agentset (using `one-of`), so it is a better solution than number two. However, although it is **perfectly fine**, from a stylistic point of view using `one-of <agentset>` reads as if you're literally looking for a single random member of the agentset, instead of looking for the specific single member of the agentset.

#3 does not even have this latter problem: even from a syntactial point of view, this approach makes it very clear that each turtle, and only such turtle, is `my-agent` of the patch it sprouted from.

Comment: Thnaks Matteo. I now better understand a list and why "sum" is used. Thank you very much for the answer and for the great explanation.

Comment: @Rafaela Note that I updated my answer with a third option, and also extended my point of view on which is the preferable option. You're welcome!